# salt in DES crypt

Tags: hash, des

How does the system know for example in an svn environment, where the account is stored inside a .passwd using DES crypt hashing, if the entered password is correct.

Correct me If i'm wrong but if I convert a certain password for example "test" using DES hashing because of the salt there are many possibilities. How does the system (I image it just compares the generated hashes) than know that the entered password is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The salt is stored in plaintext, so to speak. It is there to prevent some kinds of attacks, but the salt is only some piece of public (although site-local) information that is catenated to the password before hashing.

So let us say that your password is “test” and you work at Cyberdyne. The administrator may have decided that the salt would be “Cyber”, so that the string that gets hashed though DES is “Cybertest”.

When you input the password “test”, it is added to the local salt again before applying DES, so that the result of salting+hashing matches the stored password.

If a smart guy (or gal) has built a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) of the DES signatures of all dictionary words, he (or she) will not find your hashed password in it, because the crypted version is not DES(test), it is DES(cybertest).

Comment: so if I hash test using DES i get for example: pt8nvc2uxftei then part of this hash contains the salt correct? So different hashes are possible but all can be compared?

Comment: See http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-2.html for a very good explanation of how it all works.

Comment: @Thomas `crypt()` takes a password argument and a salt argument as a reminder to provide both, but what happens behind the scenes is basically catenation before hashing.

Comment: Ok thx for the edit; Still have a question however. In an svn environment how is this salt then determined? Edit; thx mti2935; will read that

Comment: @Thomas Actually this answer is about the general idea. From googling around, it turns out that DES is terribly limited and that, in the case of DES, the technical details are a bit sordid. I'll leave it here but it should only be taken as a general explanation and with the caveat that the details for DES are tricky.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables

Answer (score 7):

This has been pretty well answered, but just thought I'd add some additional info with a practical example.

On most modern systems, the passwords are actually stored in a shadow file /etc/shadow (which is only readable by root), not in /etc/passwd.  As a simple exercise to see how it all actually works, try the following:  As root, view the line from the shadow file for your user record:

```
cat /etc/shadow | grep yourusername
```

You will see something like this:

```
yourusername:$1$TrOIigLp$PUHL00kS5UY3CMVaiC0/g0:15020:0:99999:7:::
```

After your username there is $1.  This indicates that it is an MD5 hash.  After that there is another $, then (in this case) `TrOIigLp` followed by another $.  TrOIigLp is the salt.  After that is the hashed password, which was hashed using the salt - in this case `PUHL00kS5UY3CMVaiC0/g0`.

Now, you can use openssl to hash your password using the same salt, like so:

```
 openssl passwd -1 -salt TrOIigLp
```

Enter your user password when prompted, the openssl command should compute the MD5 hash using the salt provided, and it should be exactly the same as the above from the shadow file.  The -1 in the above command is for MD5 hashing.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks (I know this is what upvotes are for but I rarely find myself so happy to read another answer to a question I thought I had covered).